# CMake is unable to correctly generate a Unix Makefile for SDL2 project

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, build, sdl

(edit with more information at the bottom)

I have setup a CMake project that's using SDL2. The path for these libraries and include dirs are specified as system variable. The setup looks like this:

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

project(sdl2_test)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(sdl2_test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(sdl2_test ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

find-sdl2.cmake:

```
set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include")

if (${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P} MATCHES 8)
  set(SDL2_LIBRARIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/x64/SDL2.lib;${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/x64/SDL2main.lib")
else ()
  set(SDL2_LIBRARIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/x86/SDL2.lib;${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/x86/SDL2main.lib")
endif ()

string(STRIP "${SDL2_LIBRARIES}" SDL2_LIBRARIES)
```

If I tell CMake to generate a Visual Studio 2019 solution then this work perfectly. CMake finds the libraries immediately and the project can be built. Yet, when I try to generate a Unix Makefile, it does not include any of the SDL2 libraries or headers, which means that the project cannot be compiled.

```
$ cmake .. -G "Unix Makefiles"
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/c++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: E:/Code/sdl2_test/build

$ make
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sdl2_test.dir/main.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable sdl2_test.exe
c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: E:/Code/SDL2-2.0.18-devel-vc/lib/x64/SDL2main.lib(x64/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text$mn+0x84): undefined reference to `SDL_wcslen'
c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: E:/Code/SDL2-2.0.18-devel-vc/lib/x64/SDL2main.lib(x64/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text$mn+0xa2): undefined reference to `SDL_iconv_string'
c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: E:/Code/SDL2-2.0.18-devel-vc/lib/x64/SDL2main.lib(x64/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text$mn+0xb6): undefined reference to `SDL_strlen'
c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: E:/Code/SDL2-2.0.18-devel-vc/lib/x64/SDL2main.lib(x64/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text$mn+0xfb): undefined reference to `SDL_free'
c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: E:/Code/SDL2-2.0.18-devel-vc/lib/x64/SDL2main.lib(x64/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text$mn+0x122): undefined reference to `SDL_SetMainReady'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/sdl2_test.dir/build.make:103: sdl2_test.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/sdl2_test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

And the generated Makefiles does not show any signs of the libraries and headers:

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "MinGW Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.22

# Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all
.PHONY : default_target

# Allow only one "make -f Makefile2" at a time, but pass parallelism.
.NOTPARALLEL:

#=============================================================================
# Special targets provided by cmake.

# Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : %,v

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : RCS/%

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : RCS/%,v

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : SCCS/s.%

# Disable VCS-based implicit rules.
% : s.%

.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list

# Command-line flag to silence nested $(MAKE).
$(VERBOSE)MAKESILENT = -s

#Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:

# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:
.PHONY : cmake_force

#=============================================================================
# Set environment variables for the build.

SHELL = cmd.exe

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"

# The command to remove a file.
RM = "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E rm -f

# Escaping for special characters.
EQUALS = =

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = E:\Code\sdl2_test

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = E:\Code\sdl2_test\build

#=============================================================================
# Targets provided globally by CMake.

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake cache editor..."
    "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake-gui.exe" -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : edit_cache

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache/fast: edit_cache
.PHONY : edit_cache/fast

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake to regenerate build system..."
    "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --regenerate-during-build -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : rebuild_cache

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache/fast: rebuild_cache
.PHONY : rebuild_cache/fast

# The main all target
all: cmake_check_build_system
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start E:\Code\sdl2_test\build\CMakeFiles E:\Code\sdl2_test\build\\CMakeFiles\progress.marks
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start E:\Code\sdl2_test\build\CMakeFiles 0
.PHONY : all

# The main clean target
clean:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 clean
.PHONY : clean

# The main clean target
clean/fast: clean
.PHONY : clean/fast

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall: all
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall/fast

# clear depends
depend:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 1
.PHONY : depend

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named sdl2_test

# Build rule for target.
sdl2_test: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 sdl2_test
.PHONY : sdl2_test

# fast build rule for target.
sdl2_test/fast:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles\sdl2_test.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/sdl2_test.dir/build
.PHONY : sdl2_test/fast

main.obj: main.cpp.obj
.PHONY : main.obj

# target to build an object file
main.cpp.obj:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles\sdl2_test.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/sdl2_test.dir/main.cpp.obj
.PHONY : main.cpp.obj

main.i: main.cpp.i
.PHONY : main.i

# target to preprocess a source file
main.cpp.i:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles\sdl2_test.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/sdl2_test.dir/main.cpp.i
.PHONY : main.cpp.i

main.s: main.cpp.s
.PHONY : main.s

# target to generate assembly for a file
main.cpp.s:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKESILENT) -f CMakeFiles\sdl2_test.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/sdl2_test.dir/main.cpp.s
.PHONY : main.cpp.s

# Help Target
help:
    @echo The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:
    @echo ... all (the default if no target is provided)
    @echo ... clean
    @echo ... depend
    @echo ... edit_cache
    @echo ... rebuild_cache
    @echo ... sdl2_test
    @echo ... main.obj
    @echo ... main.i
    @echo ... main.s
.PHONY : help



#=============================================================================
# Special targets to cleanup operation of make.

# Special rule to run CMake to check the build system integrity.
# No rule that depends on this can have commands that come from listfiles
# because they might be regenerated.
cmake_check_build_system:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
.PHONY : cmake_check_build_system
```

Specifying "MinGW Makefiles" instead has the same issue and cannot be built due to missing libraries. Is this a known bug in CMake?

Edit: So I found out that the CMake variables for "${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS}" and "${SDL2_LIBRARIES}" are set correctly because the commands above print out the correct paths. Now, for some reason CMake is not putting those paths into the Makefile, but I don't know why?

Comment: Makefile is fine. You use different compiler now but still pass MSVC's libraries to it, is there any good reason why? While gcc may use MSVC libraries to some extent, you'll need at least `mingw32` library to be linked as well. For gcc's `ld` linker library order is important, so you'll need to linke with `mingw32 SDL2main SDL2`, in that order.

Comment: Interestingly, your makefile says `"MinGW Makefiles"`, not `"Unix Makefiles"`. AFAIK, `"MinGW Makefiles"` is intended for `mingw32-make`, and there's also `"MSYS Makefiles"` for `make` on Windows.